# jQuery subtract week from date

Tags: jquery

I have a text box id="somedate" that has a date value "09/27/2009"

I'm looking for an easy way to subtract 7 days and replace the value to 09/20/2009.
then 09/13/2009, etc...at the click of a button

Obviously I need the process to be able to cross back over months and years.

Is there an easy way of doing this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this facility exists in jQuery, but there are libraries like Datejs ([clicky](http://www.datejs.com/)) that make managing dates a lot easier. There are really too many pitfalls with date math to try to roll your own.

```
Date.parse('Sept 30th, 2009, 10:30 AM').addWeeks(-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Aside from getting the content of the input, I don't think jQuery has much to do with your problem.

You should look at the [Javascript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) for date/time calculations.

Comment: Thanks...makes sense to not always think specific to a language or framework.

Comment: Sometimes it helps stepping back and seeing that's there (:

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but this is actually pretty easy using the getTime() function of the Date object. Try something like: (use negative values to subtract)

```
Date.prototype.addWeeks = function (value) {
    var milliseconds = this.getTime();
    return new Date(milliseconds + (value * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in native JQuery, but there may or may not be libraries which makes it somewhat easier. I'd suggest you take a look at the internals of the JQuery Timepicker plugin (or one of them if there are more than one) and see what they use.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
var d = new Date($("#textbox").attr("value"));
var nd = new Date(d - new Date(7*24*60*60*1000));

function f(s) { return s[1] ? s : "0"+s; }; // ensure string is two chars long
$("#textbox").attr("value",
    f((nd.getMonth()+1).toString()) + "/" +
    f(nd.getDate().toString()) + "/" +
    nd.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if it helps.

```
var date = new Date('2013','00','10');
/* Here YYYY, Month ( 00-11 ), Date (1-31) */
alert('the original date is '+date);
var newdate = new Date(date);
newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() - 7);
var nd = new Date(newdate);
alert('the new date is '+nd);
```